# How to show all rows containing a specific name on QTableView from an sqlite database

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview

Am designing a program with Pyqt to be used to store data to an sqlite database and retrieve it using a QTableView. Apparently, i would like to retrieve a specific column like "name" and show all rows that have the name "Anderson". The following code is failing because it misses alot.

```
database = QtSql.QSqlDatabase().addDatabase('QSQLITE')
database.setDatabaseName('database.db')
database.open()
model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
#model.setQuery("SELECT Name, Sale, Date FROM Individuals")
model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
model.select()
self.tableView.setModel(model)
self.tableView.setShowGrid(False)
model.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Name")
model.setHeaderData(1, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Amount")
model.setHeaderData(2, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Date")
self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setVisible(True)
print(model.setFilter("SELECT Name = 'Anderson' FROM Individuals"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#setFilter) are reviewed:

> **void QSqlTableModel::setFilter(const QString &filter)**
>
> Sets the current filter to filter.
>
> The filter is a SQL WHERE clause without the keyword WHERE (for
> example, name='Josephine').
>
> If the model is already populated with data from a database, the model
> re-selects it with the new filter. Otherwise, the filter will be
> applied the next time select() is called.

In your case:

```
model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
model.setTable("Individuals")
model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
model.select()
model.setFilter("Name='Anderson'")
self.tableView.setModel(model)
```

Comment: when i try print(model.setFilter("Name = 'Anderson' ") it returns None

Comment: @And3r50n1 This function does not return anything, it only filters the data you see in the QTableView. What is it that you desire?

Comment: i wanted to get all rows that have the name Anderson

Comment: @And3r50n1 What do you mean by the rows, do you mean a list list that contains that information

Comment: @And3r50n1 I have updated my answer, please review it.

Comment: @And3r50n1 You have to put the model, check my answer again